# Xcode: How can I find $PRODUCT_NAME from within a shell script?

Tags: xcode, bash, scripting, build-environment

I'm writing a command-line tool that other developers will run. I'd like to extract the bundle id of the app from their Info.plist file. I can read the plist using something like PlistBuddy or Python's plistlib but I don't know how to reliably extract the $PRODUCT_NAME variable. How can I do this from a shell script?

Comment: Bundle ID or Product name? You ask both. The Product name isn't stored in the Info.plist. It's stored in the build settings.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to extract the bundle id of the app from their Info.plist file

You can get the bundle ID from the plist using PlistBuddy:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" Info.plist
```

The product name isn't likely to be available as that information is stored in the Build Settings, not the Info plist.

Comment: Yeah it just prints $(PRODUCT_NAME), are you saying it is impossible to get this value in a terminal shell script?

Comment: Ooof. 10 year old question. I'm afraid I haven't been an active developer for the last few years. I don't know about grabbing details from the build settings via the terminal now sorry.

Comment: This is fine, I ended up taking a different approach to manage all our apps and automations.